# Magento 2 Plugin - What is the $subject

Tags: magento2, plugin

What is the `$subject` in a plugin?

My code is:

```
 Class Product {
          public function afterGetPrice(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $result) { 
               return $result*2; 
               }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parameter `$subject` is the original object or class you are writing a plugin for.

See:
https://alanstorm.com/magento_2_object_manager_plugin_system/

> An after plugin method has two parameters. The first ($subject above), is the object the method was called on (in our case, that’s Pulsestorm\TutorialPlugin\Model\Example\Interceptor object). The second parameter ($result above) is the result of the original method call.

Also explained here:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

> The first argument for the before, after, and around methods is an object that provides access to all public methods of the observed method’s class.

Answer (score 1):

Plugin concepts introduced to do some function which was declared in public methods in core functions.

> getPrice() -> function available extended methods "before, after and around".

For example:

> For "x" product want to add extra price while loading product
>   page.

In our custom module will declare,

> BeforeGetPrice - this method will execute before execution core
>   Catalog Model getPrice function.
>
> AfterGetPrice - method will execute after execution core Catalog Model
>   getPrice function.
>
> AroundGetPrice - execute before and after execution core Catalog Model
>   getPrice function.

I was given simple explanation, these function have limitation please go through Magento devdocs plugin concepts.

> afterGetPrice($subject, $procees)

Parameters

> $subject -> denotes the public function which going to be replace or
>   extend the parent or original Class object.
>
> $proceed -> core function final result or return output.